# The matrix $A^2+A+m.I_n$ is non singular if $\mbox{ gcd }(m,\det\,A)=1$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A\in M_{n}(\Bbb{Z})$, $m>1$ such that $\mbox{ gcd }(m,\det\,A)=1$. Show that the matrix $A^2+A+m.I_n$ is non singular

I have tried like this: Suppose $\lambda$ be any eigenvalue of $A$. Then it is enough if we can show $\lambda^2+\lambda+m\neq0$. But how to connect this with $\mbox{ gcd }(m,\det\,A)=1$.

Answer (score 3):

If $A^2+A+mI_n$ is singular, then $A$ has an eigenvalue $\lambda$ such that $\lambda^2+\lambda+m=0$. Because $X^2+X+m$ is irreducible over $\Bbb{Z}$, this means $X^2+X+m$ divides the minimal polynomial of $A$, which in turn divides the characteristic polynomial. Then $m$ divides the constant term of the characteristic polynomial of $A$, which is $\det A$, and so $\gcd(m,\det A)=m>1$.

Comment: OK. But I want to clear a doubt: The polynomial $X^2+X-2$ is reducuble over $\Bbb{Z}$. $X^2+X-2=(X+2)(X-1)$ . So in this case will your explanation hold?

Comment: @J.Doe For that polynomial my explanation doesn't hold. But you're given that $m>1$, in which case the explanation *does* hold.

Comment: would you please explain why $X^2+X+m$ divides the minimal polynomial of $A$.

Comment: Because it is the minimal polynomial of the restriction of $A$ to the nontrivial kernel of $A^2+A+mI$.